# Client Side library interface not working in Vs 2019 and VS 2022 , Only libman.json file opening. How to enable the UI for client side library?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, client

Client Side library interface not working in Vs 2019 and VS 2022 , Only libman.json file opening. How to enable the UI for client side library in Vs 2019 and VS 2022 Asp.Net Core application ?

Comment: After using LibMan add the client side library, to use them in the Apllication, you need to add the client side library reference in the layout or main page, such as below: in the layout page, add the JQuery and Bootstrap reference:`<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>`

Comment: There is a problem in VS as the interface to add the client side library not working. So I wrote in libman.json library . Then added the script tags and its working .